# R/Shiny: If statement with Argument of length Zero

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny

I'm extremely new at R/Shiny and am trying to figure out how to do a pretty simple `if` statement. I have an `observeEvent` which for whatever reason is being triggered twice... not worried about this right now. It can be triggered where `inFile$datapath` has the actual datapath, and can be triggered when `inFile$datapath` doesn't have the file path. I'm trying to write an `if` statement to differentiate the two.

```
   shinyFileChoose(input,'file', session=session,roots=c(wd='.'))
  
  observeEvent(input$file, {
    #print(input$file)
    inFile <- parseFilePaths(roots=c(wd='.'), input$file)
    print(inFile$datapath)
    if (inFile$datapath == "") {
      print("File Exists")
    }
      else {
        session$reload()
        print("No file found.")
      }
    
  })
```

On the `print(inFile$datapath)` it outputs `character(0)`. I can't figure out a way to test that value successfully in my `if` statement without it giving me the error `Error in if: argument is of length zero`.

Comment: `observeEvent(input$file, { req(input$file$datapath); ...; })`?

Answer (score 0):

Shiny inputs are null at program startup. You have to take care of that in observeevent.

```
observeEvent(input$file, {
  if (!is.null(input$file)){
  #print(input$file)
  inFile <- parseFilePaths(roots=c(wd='.'), input$file)
  print(inFile$datapath)
  if (inFile$datapath == "") {
    print("File Exists")
  }
    else {
      session$reload()
      print("No file found.")
    }
  }    
})
```